# latexdiff hide the old version (the red crossed text)

Tags: latexdiff

My journal editor is asking for a file that highlights only additions to the document (don't ask me why). So, I don't want to see the red-crossed text (the old version or the discarded text) in the generated file by latexdiff, only the blue text (i.e. the new version or the added text).

Additional, is it possible to change the blue text color to, let's say background yellow and black text on top (like a marker highlight).

Comment: Run `latexdiff` and then add in the differences tex file `\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{} % Don't show deleted text`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One can override these commands and customize:

```
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{} % Don't show deleted text
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\color{red}\uline{#1}}}
```