# Should I be able to insert a comment environment into \textbf?

Tags: formatting, comments

For some reason,

```
\textbf{\begin{comment}X\end{comment}
Y}
```

does not compile for me, with various errors. In the following MWE, the error is

> File ended while scanning use of \next.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\begin{document}
Works (X not shown): \begin{comment}X\end{comment}

Works (Y bold): \textbf{%
Y}

Does not compile: \textbf{\begin{comment}X\end{comment}
Y}
\end{document}
```

Is this supposed not to work, and if so, why?

Comment: You are passing a verbatim environment as a macro parameter. That isn't supposed to work. What do you want to achieve? Bold font for the comment which is not shown?

Comment: @TeXnician I am using the `comment` environment in `latexdiff` to hide deleted text. Specifically, when deleting several paragraphs of text, some line breaks always remain even with https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135947, and I have found no other way to hide those.

Comment: `latexdiff --exclude-textcmd="textbf"` fixed the concrete problem, but I still wonder why a comment cannot be parsed within `\textbf`.

Answer (score 2):

Workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\begin{document}

{\bfseries 
\begin{comment}
X
\end{comment} 
Y}

\end{document}
```